# Subversion : Committing Deleted Files

Tags: svn

I'm having trouble committing files that are deleted within subversion in an efficient manner.  The commands below will illustrate my problem clearly...

```
[root@jc search]# svn st
[root@jc search]# svn rm bread_crumbs_main.6.28.2013.tpl
D         bread_crumbs_main.6.28.2013.tpl
[root@jc search]# svn commit -m "Deleting old files" ./*
[root@jc search]# svn commit -m "Deleting old files" ./bread_crumbs_main.6.28.2013.tpl
Deleting       bread_crumbs_main.6.28.2013.tpl
Committed revision 392.
[root@jc search]#
```

What I want is for the third command (commit ./*) to work.  Do I really have to manually type out every file name that I have to delete?  I'm taking over a project and there are going to be hundreds of these files I have to remove.

Thanks for any help you can provide

Comment: `svn rm` is used to mark files (in working copy) for deletion. `svn commit` is used to transfer that information to repository. Therefore your `svn commit ./*` makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to delete all files in current directory then

```
svn rm *
```

If you want to delete all files in some subdirectory then

```
svn rm subdir/*
```

If you want to delete the complete subdirectory then

```
svn rm subdir
```

When you are done deleting files (or rather marking them for deletion) you should commit the changes by naming the folder, and not just one file. If you omit the path then current folder is implied

```
svn commit -m "Deleting files"
```

Comment: Thanks.  That last bit was what I was missing.